# Getting Variable value in php

Tags: php

i have variables `$CV1`, `$CV2`, `$CV3` ... How to get the values of these variable inside while loop in PHP? Below is my code

```
$CV1=$fetch->Custom_field1;
$CV2=$fetch->Custom_field2;
$CV3=$fetch->Custom_field3;
$CV4=$fetch->Custom_field4;
$query=mysql_query("select * from customfields where CustomField like '%Invoice%' and CustomLabel != ''");
while($get=mysql_fetch_object($query))
        {
            $i++;
            $Label=$get->CustomLabel;
            $CFV='$CV'.$i;
            echo "<tr><td>$Label</td><td><input type='text' name='custom_field$i' value='$CFV'></td></tr>";
        }
```

but instead of getting the value of `$CV1`, `$CV2`. I'm getting the variable name itself as output. `$CV1`, `$CV2`, etc.

Comment: That's why we invented **arrays**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$CFV = ${'CV'.$i};
```

See [Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/V3X9hMaS)

Answer (score 2):

Use an [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead of named variables.

```
$CV[1] = $fetch->Custom_field1;
$CV[2] = $fetch->Custom_field2;
```

Then get your value this way:

```
$CFV = $CV[$i];
```

Also, don't forget to initialize `$i`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're wrapper the variable names in single quotes, which doesn't parse variable values, so you're just geting the text as is.

Try:

```
$CFV = $CV{$i};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php variable variable like this

```
$CFV="${CV$i}";
```